# Can't deploy to iPad when I add iCloud entitlement

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Using Xcode and Visual Studio for Mac:

1. In Xcode, I can make, deploy and run an out-of-the-box HelloWorld app to my provisioned iPad.
2. Also in Xcode, I can add iCloud to the same app (via entitlements), and it deploys and runs on my iPad.
3. In VS for Mac, I can make and deploy a blank Xamarin Forms HelloWorld app and it runs on my iPad.
4. However, if I add iCloud to the entitlements.plist for the Xamarin forms app, it won't deploy to my iPad.

I get the following for #4:

ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.tlZMLz/extracted/HelloWorldV.iOS.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/Huber/Projects/HelloWorldV/iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/ipad5.3-11.1.1/HelloWorldV.iOS.app' on the device 'Denny's iPad': Your code signing/provisioning profiles are not correctly configured. Probably you have an entitlement not supported by your current provisioning profile, or your device is not part of the current provisioning profile. Please check the iOS Device Log for details (error: 0xe8008016).

Application could not be uploaded to the device.

The entitlements.plist file that Xamarin generates is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>iCloud.com.DennyHuber.HelloWorldV</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-services</key>
    <array>
        <string>CloudDocuments</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have Key-Value Storage and iCloud Documents both checked.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Denny Huber

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to developer.apple.com and regenerate provisioning profile with new entitlements. After that, I advise you to manually delete all provisions, because sometimes it still tries to sign with an old one.

The provisions located in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

After that go to Xcode, Setting -> Accounts -> Select your program, and press Download Manual Profiles.

After that clean the project and try to build again.